# value_counts and normalize in groups

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe:

```
Name  |  Survey_A |  Survey_B
----------------------------
A     |  y        |  z
A     |  z        |  z
A     |  y        |  y
B     |  z        |  y
B     |  z        |  y
B     |  y        |  z
```

and I would like to get the normalized value counts of each type in Survey_A and Survey_B grouped by name.

I know how to get the value_counts using the `agg` function:

```
(df
   .groupby('Name')
   .agg({i:'value_counts' for i in
     df[['Survey_A', 'Survey_B']]})
```

which gives:

```
Name  |  type  |  Survey_A |  Survey_B
--------------------------------------
A     |  y     |  2        | 1
      |  z     |  1        | 2
B     |  y     |  1        | 2
      |  z     |  2        | 1
```

But I don't know how to get the normalized `value_counts` like the one I get using `pandas.Series.value_counts(normalize=True)`

I know how to do that on one column:

```
(df
  .groupby('Name')['Survey_A']
  .value_counts(normalize=True))
```

Which gives:

```
Name  |  type  |  Survey_A
--------------------------
A     |  y     |  0.666     
      |  z     |  0.333  
B     |  y     |  0.333   
      |  z     |  0.666
```

But not on several. I tried with:

```
(df
   .groupby('Name')
   .agg({i: lambda x:      
     x.value_counts(normalize=true) for i 
     in df[['Survey_A', 'Survey_B']]}))
```

**But with no success**.

It's possible by using a custom function like this:

```
def get_pct(g):
    output = pd.DataFrame()
    for c in g[['Survey_A', 'Survey_B']]:
        output[c] = g[c].value_counts(normalize=True)
    return output

df.groupby('Name').apply(get_pct)
```

But I wonder whether there is a more pandasish way of doing it...

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can `groupby` and get the `value_counts` and normalize it yourself but I cannot see it being any faster than your function:

```
df.groupby('Name').agg({i:'value_counts' for i in df.columns[1:]}).groupby(level=0).transform(lambda x: x.div(x.sum()))

        Survey_A    Survey_B
A   y   0.666667    0.333333
    z   0.333333    0.666667
B   y   0.333333    0.666667
    z   0.666667    0.333333
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.groupby('x').agg({'Survey_A': 'value_counts', 'Survey_B': 'value_counts'})
```

But the `NaN` values will be in output dataframe:

```
>>> df
   x x2 x3
0  A  z  a
1  A  z  a
2  A  y  d
3  B  y  a
4  B  z  d

>>> df.groupby('x').agg({'x2': 'value_counts', 'x3': 'value_counts'})
      x2   x3
A a  NaN  2.0
  d  NaN  1.0
  y  1.0  NaN
  z  2.0  NaN
B a  NaN  1.0
  d  NaN  1.0
  y  1.0  NaN
  z  1.0  NaN
```